# Grid display columns have not equal width

Tags: css, css-grid

With

```
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
```

the 2 columns have different width in small(narrow) screen. I can not understand.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: More would have been better, but I didn't downvoted this question. This is a typical problem with CSS Grid, so we can help easily.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the ideal case, the two cells will have the same size.

But every cell has a minimum size! It is defined as the minimum content width. For example: the larger word, the larger button, or the larget image that it contains.

To avoid this, you should use `minmax(0, 1fr)` for each column definition. It allows you to say that `1fr`, one fraction, is the maximum width of the column.

To sum up, use this code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
}
```

Here is a live demo of the problem and solution.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid--fix {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
}

/* Demo styles */
.grid {
  grid-gap: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.cell {
  background: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Exact same cells</p>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
</div>

<p>The cells adapt their size to contain their content</p>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell 2 is biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig</div>
</div>

<p>This behaviour could be disabled with <code>minmax(0, 1fr)</code></p>
<div class="grid grid--fix">
  <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
  <div class="cell">Cell 2 is biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really quite premature to answer so early when there's so little information to go on in the question. You are, at best, guessing at what OP's problem *will be*. Likewise, providing an answer before OP has given the minimum expected information/quality of question sends the wrong single to them and to other views that it's OK or encouraged to ask such partially-formed questions instead of providing a clear problem statement along with an MCVE for code that is not working as expected/understood.

Comment: I understand your position, but I disagree on the question evaluation. I found and find it enough to understand the problem. There is no guess here.

Comment: Thank you, it is very useful.
At last I found that I forgot a "margin-right"  rule, what was inherited from the base  CSS.
However your answer is so good, I accept this as the solution.